# ¿Como puedo posicionar dos divs uno al lado del otro con flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

Hola estoy intentando hacer una pagina responsive.Tengo un contenedor con 5 divs, en la vista movil muestro uno debajo del otro.
Lo que no me sale es cuando la pantalla es mayor o igual a 600px, quiero que el div 1 ocupe el 100% y los demas ocupen solo el 50% del ancho.
De forma que se vea 1 div arriba, y abajo 2 div uno al lado del otro por cada fila.
Pero no consigo que los div se muestren uno al lado del otro.
Esto es lo que tengo hecho.

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 800px;
}

.columna1, 
.columna2, 
.columna3, 
.columna4, 
.columna5 {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .columna2,
  .columna3, 
  .columna4, 
  .columna5 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="columna1">Sección 1</section>
    <section class="columna2">Sección 2</section>
    <section class="columna3">Sección 3</section>
    <section class="columna4">Sección 4</section>
    <section class="columna5">Sección 5</section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor añade un título que describa tu problema. Por favor revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Acabo de editar el titulo, mil disculpas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo en lo personal lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 800px;
}

.r{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background:yellow;
  flex:1;
}

.col-10, .col-5{
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.col-10{
  flex:10;
}
.col-5{
  flex:5;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .r{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background:yellow;
    flex:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="r">
      <section class="col-10">Sección 1</section>
    </div>
    <div class="r">
      <section class="col-5">Sección 2</section>
      <section class="col-5">Sección 3</section>
    </div>
    <div class="r">
      <section class="col-5">Sección 4</section>
      <section class="col-5">Sección 5</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Con todo respeto el utilizar un `width:X%` le quita todo lo que es `flexbox`, pero esa es mi opinion el hacerlo con width es depende de cada uno.

en mi caso cambio la dirección del `Main axis` en el `container`, para poder acomodar a sus hijos de forma vertical y de igual forma para la clase `r`=row=fila, y en los elementos columna=`col-x` solo aplico el `flex` para declarar la relación entre elementos.

Al hacer la media query lo único que hago es declarar la clase `r` con el `Main Axis` por defecto.

aqui el codigo en codePen -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgYbJe?editors=1100

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo adapte a mi código y funciona perfectamente :)

Answer (score 5):

!Buenas!

El problema que tienes es esta parte de aquí:

```
width: 50%;
```

Aunque le introduzcas un 50%, no quiere decir que vaya a coger la mitad de la pantalla. Tienes que hacer bien los cálculos de las medidas...

He estado probando y si cambias el valor de **50%** a un **47%** se queda como quieres.

Te dejo el código:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 800px;
}

.columna1, 
.columna2, 
.columna3, 
.columna4, 
.columna5 {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .columna2,
  .columna3, 
  .columna4, 
  .columna5 {
    width: 47%;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive design</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prueba.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="columna1">Sección 1</section>
    <section class="columna2">Sección 2</section>
    <section class="columna3">Sección 3</section>
    <section class="columna4">Sección 4</section>
    <section class="columna5">Sección 5</section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota**: He cambiado los nombres de los archivos **.css** y **.html** tenlo en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, habia probado algo parecido tambien con medidas en px, y tambien funcionaba.

Comment: Si te resolvió la duda, marca como respondida. Gracias :)

Comment: @Youshiro Aunque tu respuesta es correcta, no has explicado el porqué. El problema en sí no es que se aplique un `50%`, el problema es que está usando valores en pixeles tanto en `margin` como en `border`, esto ocupa parte del espacio que debería contener el porcentaje. Una solución conservando siempre el `50%` es eliminar el pixel en` border` y cambiar `margin` por `padding`

Comment: Pero ¿no seria logico pensar que si le pongo 50% de tamaño a ambos divs estos deberían ocupar la mitad del contenedor ? ¿que se tiene en cuenta a la hora de hacer los calculos que tu dices?

Comment: @Pablo te lo ha explicado en comentario Jheyman. Disculpa por mi breve descripción del problema.

Comment: Perfecto, tengo otra duda, por que cuando yo aplico padding a un hijo del contenedor este me sigue sin respetar el 50% y lo que hace es que me lo sigue empujandolo hacia abajo, cuando ya le quite el margin como mecionas.¿Como podria hacerlo y que me tenga en cuenta el tamaño de la caja completa con el border, padding y margin?

Comment: Con todo respeto todo lo que hacen (width: x%)no es propio de flexbox

Comment: Una buena respuesta. Observación: cuando utilizo flexbox con `flex-direction:row` no utilizo `width` sino `flex` Por ejemplo en lugar de `width: 47%;` habría utilizado `flex:1 1 47%`: ¿puede crecer? sí; ¿puede decrecer? sí; anchura: más o menos 47%